# LINQ to NHibernate by this message exception : `get_Item(Int32)`

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have a Person entity. Person has a aggregation by many Records.

```
public class Person()
{
    virtual public IList<Record> Records {get; set;}
}
```

and

```
public class Record()
{
    virtual public int Number {get; set;}
}
```

I have a linq query by NHibernate.

```
var q = SessionInstance.Query<Person>()
        .Where(x => x.Records.Any() && x.Records[0].Number>= 5);
q.ToList<Person>()
```

It is a runtime error by this message exception : `Domain.Entities.Record get_Item(Int32)`

Why?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get first element from a collection (zero based collection).
If collection is null or there's no elements that would throw an exception.

change that to

```
var q = SessionInstance.Query<Person>().Where(x => x.Records.Any() && x.Records.FirstOrDefault().Number>= 5);
q.ToList<Person>()
```

Hope it helps.

**UPDATED**

This will work, but please make sure the logic is correct.

```
var q = SessionInstance.Query<Person>().Where(x => x.Records.Any(r => r.Number >= 5));
```

Comment: this has another exception. New message exception is : Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown. [.Where[Domain.Entities.Person](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[Domain.Entities.Person], Quote((x, ) => (AndAlso(.Any[Domain.Entities.Record](x.Records, ), GreaterThanOrEqual(.FirstOrDefault[Domain.Entities.Record](x.Records, ).VolunteerFront, p1)))), )]

Comment: try this query var q = SessionInstance.Query<Person>().Where(x => x.Records.Any(r => r.Number >= 5));

Comment: but that will return any Person from the collection where Person.Records.Number >= 5. Is there a reason why you were only checking first item in your query?

Comment: Second your solution is correct but
It is my logic. The value of Number in Record is important in first record

Answer (score 0):

Your exception message is incomplete, but I believe the problem is just that the collection indexer (`get_Item()`) method support is not implemented.

I wrote a very similar piece for `IDictionary<,>`, check out [DictionaryGenerator.cs](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Linq/Functions/DictionaryGenerator.cs)

You can either open a [Jira issue](https://nhibernate.jira.com) for this, just implement and register your generator, or, better yet, open an issue, fork the repo, implement the feature and send a pull request.